# How to get the last NFT minted on candy machine

Tags: solana, nft, solana-web3js, candy-machine, solana-transaction-instruction

**After a user mints an nft, I want to get the token address or metadata and display it.**

I'm using the Candy machine's ui from Metaplex

They're using the *mintOneToken* function and it only returns a confirmation code, and that's not helpful.

```
 const mintTxId = (
   await mintOneToken(candyMachine, wallet.publicKey)
 );
```

*Response*

```
confirmationStatus: "confirmed"
```

I tried calling another function I got from Solana's cookbook , to get all the nfts minted by the current users wallet address.

But I think it fetches the data before the wallet gets updated and it doesn't retrieve the latest NFT minted

```
  const updateNfts = async () => {
    
    if (wallet.connected) {

      const ownerPublickey = wallet.publicKey;
      const nftsmetadata = await Metadata.findDataByOwner(connection, ownerPublickey);

      if(nftsmetadata.length>0){
        const amountOfNFT = nftsmetadata.length;
        console.log(nftsmetadata[amountOfNFT - 1]);
      }
    }

  }
```

How can I get the latest metadata to display it for the users? Should i set a timeout ?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Candy machine returns the mint address in random order, so you need to sort the address. I made a video on this if you want to see my solution.  https://youtu.be/INPCmnTEb3s